# Weird partition mess on KDE. Read-only file system

Tags: partition, dd, fdisk, partition-table, cfdisk

**I'm trying to partition a usb stick to NTFS.**

Before, I've wrongly flashed a windows iso using dd

```
dd if=./AME_2004_\(2020-09-16\).iso of=/dev/sdc status=progress
```

and since then I've been having problems formatting the drive.

Kde Partition Manager, cfdisk and fdisk all yield the same result when trying to partition the drive to NTFS

```
/dev/sdc read only file system
```

There isn't any physical switch on the usb, and the error doesn't seem to be caused by permissions issues. I've even tried to modify its permissions by using

```
sudo chown root:root -R /dev/sdc
sudo chmod 666 /dev/sdc
```

but the problem still persists.
Other usbs work fine.
I've tried flashing a (smaller) working usb onto the non-working one

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdd of=/dev/sdc status=progress
```

now the problem persists and I can't even use every GB of the non-working usb

```
sdc      8:32   1   7.5G  0 disk
└─sdc1   8:33   1   3.7G  0 part
```

I objectively have no idea of what I'm doing and what to do, so if you know anything just please say it right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your system is automatically mounting any disk it sees. Check if your sdc is mounted somewhere: `grep 'sdc' /proc/mounts`. If that is the case, then `umount -f /dev/sdc` a few times, until it's nowhere to be seen in `/proc/mounts`. When that's done, zero out the disk with `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc`. After that, tell the kernel to reread the disk's info: `blockdev --rereadpt /dev/sdc`. Now fdisk should have no complaints about that disk, unless of course there's something physically wrong with that disk as a coincidence.

Comment: yo, thanks for the response!
Unfortunately dd is not able to entirely write the disk with zeros :(
`~ ❯❯❯ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc status=progress
3874742272 bytes (3.9 GB, 3.6 GiB) copied, 13.0001 s, 298 MB/s`
Furthermore, this is the output of blockdev:
`~ ❯❯❯ blockdev --rereadpt /dev/sdc
blockdev: ioctl error on BLKRRPART: Inappropriate ioctl for device`

Comment: Well, things die.

Comment: lol, still thanks a lot. You made me learn a lot of stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out, the kde auto-mounting system, [udisks2](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/udisks) can cause quite a bit of trouble. Especially when trying to modify and update disk partitions.

Temporarily disabling udisk2 using  `sudo systemctl stop udisks2.service` did it for me.

Refer to [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062719/how-do-i-disable-the-auto-mounting-of-internal-drives-in-ubuntu-or-kubuntu-18-04) for more